# Как поставить задержку на Observable RxJava2?

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Вот есть был такой метод

```
public List<String> search(String iQuery)
{
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(700);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException iE)
            {
                iE.printStackTrace();
            }

            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String iStr : mSettlementList)
            {
                if (iStr.toLowerCase().contains(iQuery.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    result.add(iStr);
                }
            }

            return result;
}
```

Тут стоит задержка для того, чтоб когда выполняется поиск прогрес бар успел сделать работу а не сразу судорожно появлялся и исчезал. Ну и потом сортировка и возврат результата

Теперь точно это же я хочу сделать с помощью Rx2

Вот, что получилось

```
public List<String> search(String iQuery)
{
    return Observable.fromIterable(mSettlementList)//
                     .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//
                     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//
                     .filter(iStr -> iStr.toLowerCase().contains(iQuery.toLowerCase()))//
                     .toList()//
                     .blockingGet();
}
```

Вроде все работает, но вот только задержки нет...

Как ее сюда добавить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте оператор [delay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) :

```
Observable.fromIterable(mSettlementList)
                 .delay(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                 .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                 .filter(iStr -> iStr.toLowerCase().contains(iQuery.toLowerCase()))
                 .toList()
                 .blockingGet();
```